# How to make struct LazyList in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I use ScrollView+LazyVStack+ForEach instead of standart List.

**How to make wrapper around this?**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items = ["1", "2", "3"]
    var body: some View {
       LazyList(data: items) { item in
         
       }
    }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct LazyList<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable {

    public var data: Data
    public var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(data, content: content)
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Comment: I believe a List() is already Lazy... https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651256

Comment: @nicksarno  no, it is not lazy. At least on MacOS absolutely sure it is not lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 2021, SwiftUI 2

Apple lies in `wwdc20-10031` when telling that List is lazy.

## List IS NOT LAZY on MacOS.

(I don't know about iOS)

About the question. Your code is wrong. This must work:

```
public struct LazyList<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, Data.Element: Identifiable, ID : Hashable, Content: View {

    public var data: Data
    public var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(data, content: content)
            }
        }
    }
}
```